# Oracle: how to count number of inserts in a database between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to count the number of inserts into user created tables between two dates. 
For example, if there are 5 inserts into 4 tables out of a total of 20 tables. Is there a way to do this without running a query for each table?

Comment: You can use `union all`.

Comment: Do you tables have a column for storing insert date, or do you want to somehow scrap the info from system tables?

Comment: How do you know the number of inserts into a user created table between two dates?

Comment: @Timekiller yes, all of them have a created_date column. I was thinking maybe there is some system table that stores this kind of information.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @MontySwanson the DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS stores those informations. But you'll need to run the FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO procedure in the DIMS_STATS PL/SQL package to populate this view with the latest information.

Comment: What do you mean by "inserts"? Normally that means number of INSERT operations (whether inserting one row or 100 million rows in a single statement). The CREATED DATE column in a table doesn't tell you how many rows were inserted in one go. Or do you need to count how many individual rows were inserted during your target window?

Comment: @mathguy I now realized I may need two different things. One is the number of individual rows inserted and the other is the number of updates (the result of update table sql commands)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will display the table name and the number of inserts, updates and deletes :

```
select
   table_owner,
   table_name,
   inserts,
   updates,
   deletes
from
   dba_tab_modifications
where
   timestamp > sysdate-1;
```

But you'll need to run the FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO procedure in the DIMS_STATS PL/SQL package to populate this view with the latest information.

You will found the procedure to gather all stats from your DB here : https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68568

Note that you'll need the `ANALYZE_ANY` privilege to launch the procedure.

**To summarize** : run the `FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO` to update all the changes on the DB and then use the `DBMS_STATS`. The `DBMS_STATS` gather automatically the "stale" objects which are objects in need of being analyzed. And then launch the request from the `DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS` to print the changes.